# How can we know a method is a callback method in android

Tags: android, methods, callback

I know onCreate , onListItemClick and onPageSelected etc. are callback methods in android.
Yet some are not so obvious to tell they are callback methods, 
for example, getItem method in class FragmentStatePagerAdapter. 
(Isn't it? Or getItem is not a callback method?)

How can we know a method is a callback method in android?
Is there any clue to let people know they are callback methods?
Or is there a list of all callback methods in android?

Comment: chekc the api list..

Comment: How will you use this information? How do you define a "callback" method? It sounds like you are just looking for [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Comment: @Tim , thanks. Could you tell me more about the api list? Where to find it and how can it show us the callback methods?

Comment: @Tanis.7x , I need the information so I can use those methods properly. Or I might use the callback method in wrong way. A callback method is a method called and used by android system, like onCreate or some methods in some listener classes. I am confused now because I can't tell if a method is a callback one or not. There should be some way to recognize them.

Comment: @mizuc http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html here is  the list, but is huge, how to recognise them? code more..

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for each class at the Android developers site will list all of the methods available to you as a developer.

Take the [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) class for example. We can generally sort the methods into two large buckets:

- Methods that are **final** such as [`getApplication()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication())
- Methods that are not final, such as [`onCreate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle))

Methods that fall into the first bucket you can immediately rule out from what you refer to as "callback" methods. Since they are final, you cannot override their behavior.

Methods that fall into the second bucket might be a "callback." I wouldn't get hung up on trying to label them as such though. Each and every method in the `Activity` class *may or may not* get called by some other piece of code at some point in time. However, most of those methods exist because they *will* get called at some point in time.

Even some of the methods that you might not think of as a "callback" method can be overridden and can be called by the framework (or your own code). For example, you can override the [`finish()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()) method of an Activity. Most applications will only ever call `finsh()` directly without customizing the behavior, but you do have that option.

Focus on what you need to do, find the appropriate method to either call or override, then read the documentation on that method. Whether or not the method is a "callback" is usually irrelevant.

Comment: one way to determine the method is callback, by looking at the function parameters, what kind of parameters it is returning to u

Comment: @Tanis.7x , the reason I asked this is because I read android developer's sample app of animation demo. It used getItem method and never called getItem in the code. Yet the getItem was effective indeed and changed the result. Someone had the same question , [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532954/how-are-the-views-for-this-view-pager-being-created). And I later found someone said getItem is a callback method, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280736/callbacks-for-adapter-interface-in-android). If there is more description in documentaion, won't it be better for users?

Comment: I feel as though [the documentation for `getItem()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem(int)) is sufficient. The method is `abstract`, so you know you need to override it. The documentation also clearly states that this method should return the item at the specified position. What else do you need?

Comment: @Tanis.7x , maybe the documentation can add some description about when the framework will call getItem() and under what conditions? Maybe those details will make the documentation become too complicated to write/read? Or maybe I will find the current documentation is enough for users later when I get more familiar to android? Thanks a lot for your comprephensive reply.